# How can I get html column of gridview to prepopulate form from database?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, gridview

I have an asp.net webform that has a few checkboxes & texboxes and on submit the data is stored on SQL server.

I have a separate webform that consists of a gridview that consists of the data from the form.

I would like to add an additional column to the gridview that has an html link for each record that reloads and populates the form based on the submitted data to the database.

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="GridDataSource">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SiteID" HeaderText="ID"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date"></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I have working code that can populate the form checkboxes from my database below:

C# Codebehind:

```
SqlCommand cmd = null;
string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
string queryString = @"SELECT AA, BB, CC FROM Test " +
    "WHERE SITE_ID = @SiteID";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    connection.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString);
    cmd.Connection = connection;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SiteID", //the name of the parameter to map
          System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, //SqlDbType value
          20, //The width of the parameter
          "SITE_ID")); //The name of the column source
    //Fill the parameter with the value retrieved
    //from the text field
    cmd.Parameters["@SiteID"].Value = 500;

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        CheckBox1.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("AA")));
        CheckBox2.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("BB")));
        CheckBox3.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("CC")));
    }
}
```

My issue is as you can see in the code is that it will only return the values from the SiteID that = 500.  I would like the html column to associate the SiteID to each record and when clicking on the link it opens the form with the populated data from that SiteID. Is this possible?  I hope i'm making sense here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a `TemplateField`. In that template you can create a link to the details page, or if it is on the same page, a button with the correct `SiteID`

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Link">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a href="/Details?SiteID=<%# Eval("SiteID") %>">Click here</a>

            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("SiteID") %>'>Click here</asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion VDWWD.  Now I seem to have another issue.  When I click on the link, it doesn't make the changes although I see it in the address bar.  I'm sure it's because of this line in my codebehind: cmd.Parameters["@SiteID"].Value = 500;  What should I modify this to?

Comment: I figured it out.  I needed to add string SiteID = Request.QueryString["SiteID"];    Also, I needed to change 500 to SiteID.